# Divide a googolplex into two numbers with no prime factor under 100

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

Very likely, a googolplex won't be Goldbached into 2 provably prime numbers in my lifetime.  But it seems possible to do a split that can avoid small primes.  The first 24 odd primes have a product of $k=1152783981972759212376551073665878035$, and it's easy to calculate that a googolplex mod $k$ is $x =929084311939231970567712621104570410$, which is prime when 509 is subtracted. I'm not sure what the next steps would be.

Can you divide a googolplex into two odd numbers where neither is divisible by any odd prime 97 or under?  If so, how high up can you push that before it starts being computationally challenging?

Comment: The known result on Goldbach's conjecture already implies that every sufficiently large even number can be written as the sum of either two primes, or a prime and a semiprime (the product of two primes).

Comment: I'm wondering how far a constructive method can be taken on an arbitrarily large number.

Comment: @CaveJohnson, doesn't the known result allow for small primes or semiprimes in the decomposition?  I.e., even if a googleplex is sufficiently large, the known result wouldn't seem to help here.

Answer (score 2):

Definitions:

- googolplex: $g = 10^{10^{100}}$;
- $k$-rough number: a positive integer whose prime factors are all greater than or equal to $k$ (see [Rough number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_number));
- primorial $p_n\#$: $\quad p_n\# = \prod\limits_{k=1}^n p_k$, where $p_k$ is $k$-th prime number (see [Primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial)).

---

Suppose we want to write $$g = a+b,\tag{1}$$
where $a,b$ are $20$-rough numbers.

Consider all remainders $g (\bmod p_k)$, where $p_k\le 20$.
And choose remainders for $a$ and $b$, such that

- $a,b \not \equiv 0 (\bmod p_k)$;
- $a+b\equiv g (\bmod p_k)$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
p_k & g (\bmod p_k) & a (\bmod p_k) & b (\bmod p_k) \\
\hline
2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
5 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
7 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
11 & 1 & 2 & 10 \\
13 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\
17 & 1 & 2 & 16 \\
19 & 9 & 1 & 8 \\
\hline
\end{array}
Note that there are many cases for $a,b$ remainders; here is one of them.

Then (to reconstruct $a$ from its remainders) applying [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), 
one can enter

```
ChineseRemainder[{1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1},{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19}]
```

in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ChineseRemainder%5B%7B1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1%7D,%7B2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19%7D%5D) and get that

$$a \equiv 8835191 (\bmod 19\#);\tag {2}$$

and

```
ChineseRemainder[{1,2,4,3,10,2,16,8},{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19}]
```

gives us

$$b \equiv 1054679 (\bmod 19\#),\tag{3}$$

where 
$19\# = p_8\# =  2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 = 9699690$.

So we can choose $a = 8835191$, $b = g-a$.

Or $a = 9699690 k + 8835191$, where $k$ is appropriate non-negative integer number.

---

For writing googolplex in the form $(1)$ (at least one of examples), where $a,b$ are $100$-rough, we expand previous table to the form:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
p_k & g (\bmod p_k) & a (\bmod p_k) & b (\bmod p_k) \\
\hline
2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
5 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
7 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
11 & 1 & 2 & 10 \\
13 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\
17 & 1 & 2 & 16 \\
19 & 9 & 1 & 8 \\
23 & 13 & 1 & 12 \\
29 & 24 & 1 & 23 \\
31 & 5 & 1 & 4 \\
37 & 10 & 1 & 9 \\
41 & 1 & 2 & 40 \\
43 & 24 & 1 & 23 \\
47 & 9 & 1 & 8 \\
53 & 46 & 1 & 45 \\
59 & 48 & 1 & 47 \\
61 & 47 & 1 & 46 \\
67 & 10 & 1 & 9 \\
71 & 45 & 1 & 44 \\
73 & 1 & 2 & 72 \\
79 & 52 & 1 & 51 \\
83 & 10 & 1 & 9 \\
89 & 16 & 1 & 15 \\
97 & 35 & 1 & 34 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Then, applying

```
 ChineseRemainder[
    {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {2, 3, 5, 7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97}]
```

we have
$$
a \equiv 1\: 744\: 949\: 340\: 521\: 974\: 476\: 409\: 807\: 187\: 663\: 679\: 281
(\bmod 97\#),
$$
where $$97\# = p_{25}\# = 2\: 305\: 567\: 963\: 945\: 518\: 424\: 753\: 102\: 147\: 331\: 756\: 070.$$

Comment: Oh, that's brilliant.  So it looks like we can make numbers of arbitrary roughness with arbitrary size.